# View doesn't show updated data after POST action

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to load a partial view and change it through a POST Ajax, but model doesn't update on view.

This is how I'm loading my partial:

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction("UltimeNovità", "User");
}
```

and my action in UserController is:

```
 public ActionResult UltimeNovità()
    {
        _UltimeNovitàViewModel model = new _UltimeNovitàViewModel();
        model.NumeroPagina = 1;

        return PartialView("~/Views/User/Partial/_UltimeNovità.cshtml",model);
    }
```

and here the partial:

```
@model Mine.Models._UltimeNovitàViewModel

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
});

function nextPage() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UltimeNovitàPaginaSuccessiva")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { pagina: @Model.NumeroPagina },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#x').text('@Model.NumeroPagina');
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}

</script>

<p id="x">1</p>
```

finally, the POST action in the same controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UltimeNovitàPaginaSuccessiva(int pagina)
    {            
        _UltimeNovitàViewModel model = new _UltimeNovitàViewModel();
        ModelState.Clear();
        model.NumeroPagina = pagina + 1;
        model.UltimeNovità = UserControllerMethods.GetUltimeNovità(model.NumeroPagina);

        return PartialView("~/Views/User/Partial/_UltimeNovità.cshtml", model);
    }
```

My problem is: why after the POST action @Model.NumeroPagina is always 1? I expect that each time I press the button which calls the function with ajax the @Model.NumeroPagina increases by 1 and it's shown in my paragraph.

The button is in the main page that contains the partial, actions are always hit and during debugging I can see that model.NumeroPagina is 2, but in view is always 1.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code. I don't see where you're updating the HTML content, also you're generating the `nextPage` function eachTime, and others.

Check this sample, it should be easy to use.

**Controller/ViewModel**

```
public class NovitàController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult UltimeNovità(int? page)
    {
        var model = new UltimeNovitàViewModel
        {
            NumeroPagina = 1
        };
        return PartialView("_UltimeNovità", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UltimeNovitàPaginaSuccessiva(int pagina)
    {
        var model = new UltimeNovitàViewModel
        {
            NumeroPagina = pagina + 1,
            UltimeNovità = GetUltimeNovità(pagina + 1)
        };

        return PartialView("_UltimeNovità", model);
    }

    public string GetUltimeNovità(int page)
    {
        return $"Ultime Novità: {page}"; //FOR DEMO
    }

    public class UltimeNovitàViewModel
    {
        public int NumeroPagina { get; set; }
        public string UltimeNovità { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`_UltimeNovità` partial view:

```
@model NovitàController.UltimeNovitàViewModel

@if (Model.UltimeNovità != null)
{
    <div>
        UltimeNovità: @Model.UltimeNovità
    </div>
}

<div>
    Pagina: @Model.NumeroPagina
</div>

<div>
    <a class="next-page-link" href="@Url.Action("UltimeNovitàPaginaSuccessiva", "Novità", new {pagina = Model.NumeroPagina})">
        Pagina Successiva
    </a>
</div>
```

And the `Index` page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Novità";
}

<div id="RootDiv">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("UltimeNovità", "Novità");}
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function() {
            function bindNextPageLink() {
                $("#RootDiv a.next-page-link").click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    $.post($(this).attr("href"),
                        function(data) {
                            $("#RootDiv").html(data);
                            bindNextPageLink();
                        }
                    );
                });
            }

            bindNextPageLink();
        });
    </script>
}
```

I tried to write the example very similar to your code.